# Error when loading JS program on RPI boot

Tags: javascript, cron, raspberry-pi, boot

I am trying to start a Javascript/nodejs program on the boot of my raspberry pi.
I am logging the program errors to a file and it says that i cannot connect to my database and the program stops.
when i run the program in the terminal it runs fine!

i use this code in the crontab file: (with this command : sudo crontab -e).

@reboot sleep 10 | node /PATH/index.js &

the error that i get looks like:
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to [SERVER]:1433 - getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN [SERVER]

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`@reboot` fires a command once when the cron daemon starts up; it's likely the case that the cron daemon is starting before your DB service. What you probably want to be doing instead is making your own 'Simple'-type service that has an 'After' dependency of your DB service, so you know its there.